# How to fix tqdm progress_apply for pandas in Jupyter?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tqdm

Don't really understand is it a mistake or just my local problem, still have some issues with using [tqdm progress bars](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) with *progress_apply* in Jupyter.

**First try:**

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm_notebook.pandas(desc="Example Desc")
keywords_df['keyword'] = keywords_df['keywird'].progress_apply(lambda x: x.replace('*',''))
```

**Output** (without any bars)**:**

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pandas'
```

**Second try:**

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm_notebook().pandas(desc="Example Desc")
keywords_df['keyword'] = keywords_df['keywird'].progress_apply(lambda x: x.replace('*',''))
```

**Output:**
Two bars (need one). First bar is empty (0it [00:00, ?it/s]), second is OK.

Any ideas how to change *progress_apply* description and display bar without empty initialization bar? :)

**P.S.**
Documentation (https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm) says I can just use *tqdm_notebook*, but it's not working for me :)

```
# Register `pandas.progress_apply` and `pandas.Series.map_apply` with `tqdm`
# (can use `tqdm_gui`, `tqdm_notebook`, optional kwargs, etc.)
tqdm.pandas(desc="my bar!")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Answer](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/419) from tqdm developer:

> notebook support is still in a (late) beta stage. The API might change
>   slightly when we release tqdm v5 but for now you probably need

```
from tqdm._tqdm_notebook import tqdm_notebook

tqdm_notebook.pandas(...
```

Answer (score 49):

Now you can just do:

```py
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

df.progress_apply(...)
```

My version of tqdm is 4.39.0

Answer (score 11):

This is what I run in my jupyter notebooks, and then progress_apply works:

```
from tqdm import tqdm, tqdm_notebook
tqdm_notebook().pandas()
```

I had been getting an error without the () after tqdm_notebook

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your question is about how to use the status bar, vs the ascetics of the status bar on the Jupyter NoteBook then your code should be

```
tqdm.pandas(desc="Example Desc")
keywords_df['keyword'] = keywords_df['keywird'].progress_apply(lambda x: x.replace('*',''))
```

Comment: Ascetics quite important, because it's the main reason to use tqdm_notebook (not just tqdm). Also, tqdm_notebook works with nested bars, while static tqdm has some issues with colorama :)

Answer (score 8):

The following is working for me:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()
keywords_df['keyword'] = keywords_df['keywird'].progress_apply(lambda x: x.replace('*',''))
```