# How can I get a tqdm progress_apply bar in VS Code notebooks?

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I am trying to display a progress bar when I perform "vector" `progress_apply` operations on pandas dataframes, in MS Visual Studio Code.

In VS Code with the [Python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python#review-details) enabled, I tried in a cell

```
import pandas as pd 
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook, tqdm_pandas 

tqdm_notebook().pandas()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['foo', 'bar'], 'b' : ['spam', 'eggs']}) 
df.progress_apply(lambda row: row['a'] + row['b'], axis = 1)
```

And the result is not OK (edit: this may actually render fine on more recent versions of VS Code).

[image: progress bar render fails with vscode]

How can I visualize the progress bar when I run pandas `progress_apply` in vscode?

Comment: Perhaps related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45595689/how-to-fix-tqdm-progress-apply-for-pandas-in-jupyter/51085407

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Revisiting this in 2022 (VS Code 1.63.2), the code below will work fine in VS code, and may be more appealing visually than the other solution I previously had for this:

```
import pandas as pd 
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

tqdm.pandas()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['foo', 'bar'], 'b' : ['spam', 'eggs']}) 
df.progress_apply(lambda row: row['a'] + row['b'], axis = 1)
```

[image: VS code tqdm bar render]

Answer (score 3):

This version worked fine on my version of vscode and python extension:

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['foo', 'bar'], 'b' : ['spam', 'eggs']})
df.progress_apply(lambda row: row['a'] + row['b'], axis = 1)
```

[image: Fix]